# Laravel relations - multiple table joining - 4 tables

Tags: laravel

*Table A*
**id**----  **B_id**------  **C_id**

1------ 1------------1

2-------2------------2

*Table B*

**id**---**name**-----------**D_ID**

1----merchant1-----1

2----merchant2------2

*Table C*

**id**--**reason**

1---reason1

2---reason2

*Table D*
**id**--**market**
1   market1

2   market2

I want the result like this.

```
[{
id=>1,
B_ID =>1,
B_name=>merchant1,
D_ID=>1,
market=>market1,
C_id=>1,
reason=>reason1},{
id=>2,
B_ID =>2,
B_name=>merchant2,
D_ID=>2,
market=>market2,
C_id=>2,
reason=>reason2}]
```

I got this answer from direct queries. 
I want to know is it possible using laravel relations and models?
If yes could you please tell how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can query for model A and eager load the rest of the models:

```
$modelA->with(['modelB.modelD', 'modelC'])->get();
```

For it to work you need a relationship on model A for modelB and modelC, and a relationship on modelB for modelD.

**UPDATE**

You can map over the results, for example like this:

```
$modelACollection->map(function($modelA) {
    return [ "id" => $modelA->id,
             "B_ID" => $modelA->modelB->id,
             "B_name => $modelA->modelB->name,
             "D_id" => $modelA->modelB->modelD->id,
             "market" => $modelA->modelB->modelD->market,
             "C_id" => $modelA->modelC->id,
             "reason" => $modelA->modelC->reason
    ]
```

Comment: Returning all the results. But Please have a look into my desired result.
This is returnig the object like [{
id=>1,
'modelB'=>[{
 B_ID =>1,
 B_name=>merchant1,
 'modelC'=>[{
  C_id=>1,
  market=>market1,
 }]
}],
'modelD'=>[{
 D_ID=>1,
 reason=>reason1
 }]
}]

This is not the format I expected.
anyhow  **'modelB.modelD'** this one is new for me. Thank you

Comment: The structure is dependent on the relationships you have setup. If you have a 1:1 relationship it will be returned as desired, eg. not a collection.